# How to start a interactive Chef client just like start a rails by "rails console"?

Tags: chef-infra

In chef workstation client, I want to start an interactive console to debug and check the role/recipe, or use search api, e.g.

```
 chef-client > nodes=search ("node","name:*")
 chef-client > puts "#{nodes}"
```

...

Just like in rails, use "rails console" to load all your rails environment into irb.

How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "shef" tool may be what you're looking for, it starts an IRB session in your chef environment where you can do things like search, browse and manipulate your nodes, roles, etc.    There's even a debugger to step through your recipes using the "breakpoint" resource.

Here's a real basic example

```
chef > nodes.list
=> [node[db1-production], node[worker1-production], node[app1-production]]
chef > nodes.show('app1-production').class
 => Chef::Node
```

etc.. check out the OpsCode wiki page about it: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Shef

Comment: It should be pointed out that `shef` has been replaced by `chef-shell`.